# how to solve the os errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

- Lately I have been working on Ctypes. I have a `.C` file let me call
  it `ABC.C`.
- It has many functions I just need to call this
  `Algorithm_Interface` function in python using `Ctypes`.
- I tried using `gcc` to create a `.so`(like a library file) file `from geeks for geeks` source .`gcc -fPIC -shared -o libfun.so ABC.c`
- And by using that command , in the `.C` source file directory. A `.so` file is created(libfun.so).

In python I used this code to call that function:

```
import ctypes
f=open( "data.txt","r")
Raw_file=f.read()
fun = ctypes.CDLL("D:/NR/SPO2/libfun.so")
fun.Algorithm_Interface.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
returnVale = fun.Algorithm_Interface(Raw_file)
```

While I try to run it it returns a error.

```
[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

how to solve this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses .dll and .exe for applications. The .so is compiled for a different system (like Linux).

Python ctypes uses regular Windows functions by the looks of it, and thus also only support .dll.

You need a version of gcc that produce Windows binaries to compile your C source code before you can load it on Windows.

There's a lot of different distributions of GCC for Windows, like for example Mingw. Just google "GCC for Windows".

Once you have a Windows based GCC installed, use that in place of your current gcc, but use libfun.dll for in place of libfun.so.

Comment: What different between DL and .SO

Comment: .SO is the equivalent of .DLL on Linux and similar systems. Both are implementations of shared libraries, but on the different platforms.

Comment: gcc --version
gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. "Is this what you mean " @marpor

Comment: Yes, did that work?

Comment: No @marpor, it didn't work

Comment: Guess that it has some other problems...

Comment: Are you getting a different error now, or the same?

Comment: If you get the *same* error, it may also be because you are mixing 32- and 64-bit versions. If you are running 32-bit Python it will only load 32-bit DLLs. So make sure you get the same version of both Python and GCC.